# wrapping const char* in Monotouch

Tags: objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I had some issues using some classes from a Monotouch wrapped Dll. Some of the methods have parameters of type (const char*) in Objective-C which I translated to string when creating the wrapper.
Everything is going good so far. The problem is that one class that I have tries to make a socket connection to a url. I created a string variable containing the name of the url but in the generate log of the Dll I always see the url in special characters like this �X�� and it says that the hostname is unknown. Below are examples of two methods in Obj-C and C#:

```
- (BOOL) open:(const char*)method withUrl:(const char*)url withAsync:(BOOL)isAsync;

[Export ("open:withUrl:withAsync:")]
bool Open (string method, string url, bool isAsync);
```

and another one:

```
- (id)init:(const char*)url onPort:(int)port andUseSSL:(BOOL)ssl;

[Export ("init:onPort:andUseSSL:")]
IntPtr Constructor (string url, int port, bool ssl);
```

The first method represents a customized httpRequest. I even tried to encode the string using Encoding.UTF8 but with no luck.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening ?

Thanks

Comment: Could be garbage (corruption) or encoding issues. Can you edit your question and shows the original definitions and how you translated them into C# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generator included with MonoTouch transform C# `System.String` to Objective-C `NSString`. That's the most common string representation used in Objective-C (for iOS and MonoMac).

However that's not the same as a C/C++ `char*` (which is also supported in Objective-C since it's a superset of C).

You'll need to use an `IntPtr` (instead of a `string`) and marshal the string yourself.

Comment: Great :-) To help others please mark the question as answered (grey mark under the votes/up/down) as it will help future searches for similar issues. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out voting requires 15 reputations and I just have 11 (I am new), so I will do it as soon as I can.